# How can I automatically create (and remove) a temp directory in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, temporary-files

Is it possible to have `make` create a temp directory before it executes the first target? Maybe using some hack, some additional target etc.?

All commands in the Makefile would be able to refer to the automatically created directory as `$TMPDIR`, and the directory would be automatically removed when the `make` command ends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I seem to recall being able to call make recursively, something along the lines of:

```
all:
    -mkdir $(TEMPDIR)
    $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) old_all
    -rm -rf $(TEMPDIR)

old_all: ... rest of stuff.
```

I've done similar tricks for calling make in subdirectories:

```
all:
    @for i in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        echo "make all in $$i..."; \
        (cd $$i; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) all); \
    done
```

Just checked it and this works fine:

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
    -mkdir tempdir
    -echo hello >tempdir/hello
    -echo goodbye >tempdir/goodbye
    $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) old_all
    -rm -rf tempdir

old_all:
    ls -al tempdir

$ make all
mkdir tempdir
echo hello >tempdir/hello
echo goodbye >tempdir/goodbye
make  old_all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pax'
ls -al tempdir
total 2
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 allachan None 0 Feb 26 15:00 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 4 allachan None 0 Feb 26 15:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 allachan None 8 Feb 26 15:00 goodbye
-rw-r--r--  1 allachan None 6 Feb 26 15:00 hello
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pax'
rm -rf tempdir

$ ls -al tempdir
ls: cannot access tempdir: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That works, but of course only if the user says 'make' without specifying a target. So 'make all' won't work etc.

Comment: I expect the user to know what they're doing :-) so they would use "make" or "make toplevel". In any case, you can change "all" to "old_all" and "toplevel" to "all" if you want that behavior.

Comment: Updated so that you can "make all" which is also the default rule.

Comment: What are the dashes before mkdir etc. for?

Comment: @nnnmmm, they tell `make` to ignore the return code of the command. Otherwise, a failure would cause `make` to stop.

Answer (score 26):

These previous answers either didn't work or seemed overly complicated. Here is a far more straight forward example I was able to figure out:

```
PACKAGE := "audit"
all:
    $(eval TMP := $(shell mktemp -d))
    @mkdir $(TMP)/$(PACKAGE)
    rm -rf $(TMP)
```

Comment: Works like a charm in GNU make. But not in BSD make.

Comment: Doesn't clean up if there are any errors which is kind of the point :)

Answer (score 23):

With GNU make, at least,

```
TMPDIR := $(shell mktemp -d)
```

will get you your temporary directory. I can't come up with a good way to clean it up at the end, other than the obvious `rmdir "$(TMPDIR)"` as part of the `all` target.

Comment: If all targets are up to date, then evaluating `TMPDIR` will create the directory, and `all`'s rules will never be executed to delete it.

Comment: @Josh Kelley: .PHONY will take care of that.

Comment: This will create a temp file every time you execute *any* recipe, right?  How will a `.PHONY` target take care of deleting `TMPDIR`?

Comment: @AriSweedler that was assuming `all` was the only target, I think. Or that there are only a few targets, so you can remove from each.

Comment: provide `mktemp -p myprefix -d` and `rm -rf myprefix*`

Comment: Attention: this will create a new tempdir every time using the "variable"! Had to use TMPDIR := $(realpath $(shell mktemp -d))

Answer (score 11):

See [Getting the name of the makefile from the makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400057/getting-the-name-of-the-makefile-from-the-makefile/1400184#1400184) for the `$(self)` trick

```
ifeq ($(tmpdir),)

location = $(CURDIR)/$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))
self := $(location)

%:
    @tmpdir=`mktemp --tmpdir -d`; \
    trap 'rm -rf "$$tmpdir"' EXIT; \
    $(MAKE) -f $(self) --no-print-directory tmpdir=$$tmpdir $@

else
# [your real Makefile]
%:
    @echo Running target $@ with $(tmpdir)
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your Makefile

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
export TMPDIR:=$(shell mktemp -d ./.make-tmp_XXXXXXXX)
$(info Launching clean up task for ${TMPDIR})
$(shell { trap 'rm -rf ${TMPDIR};' EXIT; tail --pid=$$PPID -f /dev/null; } \
           </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &)
```

The cleanup happens when the `make`-process finishes using the parent PID ($PPID) of the shell.  Using the `trap`-setup the cleanup happens also when make does not finish properly or is interrupted.

I use this inclosed in an `ifeq` in the following way:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
ifdef MAKELEVEL
    ifeq "${MAKELEVEL}" "0"
        export TD:=$(shell mktemp -d ./.make-tmp_XXXXXXXX)
        $(info Launching clean up task for ${TD})
        $(shell { trap 'rm -rf ${TD};' EXIT; tail --pid=$$PPID -f /dev/null; } \
           </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &)
    endif
endif
```

This ensures that only the top-level make will create the directory and the sub-makes can then use the same directory.  Thus the `export`.

Likely only works on linux with `bash` as the shell, thus the `SHELL := /bin/bash`.

Hope that helps.