# Recursive make with nonstandard makefile name on old make version

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which calls itself, in order to obtain a license for the compiler before compiling anything, and release the license even when compilation fails, like this:

```
.PHONY main_target
main_target:
    @license_grab &
    @sleep 2
    -@$(MAKE) real_target
    @license_release
```

This works great if the makefile is named "makefile". But if I make a copy of the makefile to experiment with something, and invoke it with `make -f makefile_copy`, then the wrong makefile gets used in the recursive call. How do I prevent this without hard-coding the makefile name in the makefile itself?

**Edit:** Unfortunately I'm stuck using GNU Make version 3.79.1, so I cannot use MAKEFILE_LIST, which was apparently [introduced in version 3.80](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-make@gnu.org/msg05902.html). Therefore none of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1400057/1390430) will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the MAKE variable outside the makefile, to include the makefile name (unless of course, it gets overridden).  Something like this (for bash):

```
MAKE="make -f makefile_copy" make -e -f makefile_copy
```

or this (in pretty much any shell):

```
make MAKE="make -f makefile_copy" -f makefile_copy
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like an elegant workaround. The better answer of course is to use a more recent `make` supporting MAKEFILE_LIST as in the other answer, but this should do in a pinch.

Comment: I use this in a few of my programs - while doing recursive makes passing the MAKE and MAKEFLAGS symbols in the recursive calls (to ensure that it those were set in the lower-levels, that they're overridden).

Comment: This works great for bash, for csh I used `make MAKE="make -f makefile_copy" -f makefile_copy`. It seemed to work, but is that actually equivalent or am I missing something subtle?

Comment: With the "-e", it is equivalent.  Passing environment variables into programs like that is just a habit I picked up, long ago.  "make" has long had (checking SunOS 4...) the `variable=value` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable:

```
THIS_MAKEFILE := $(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))

.PHONY main_target
main_target:
        @license_grab &
        @sleep 2
        -@$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE) real_target
        @license_release
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great answer for recent versions of make. Unfortunately the version I'm using is very out of date and doesn't have support for MAKEFILE_LIST; I added that info to my question.

Comment: Then you're out of luck.  You'll have to either set a variable on the command line by hand or hardcode the file name.  You can write a little shell alias or script wrapper around make that will do it for you, but there's no really reliable way to do it from within the makefile.